In-Store Delivery Stock Transfers
I have a stock warehouse and 20 different store locations that someone can pick up their purchase from. I have implemented the In-Store Delivery shipping method, with 21 different non-default sources, where 1 is the ecommerce warehouse and the other 20 are pick up location enabled. I have 1 non-default stock that has all 21 sources assigned that feeds the stock on my site. Everything is working fine on that end. I have a question about fulfilling the orders.
For example, I have 20 units of a product in the ecommerce warehouse, and a customer orders 1 unit to be picked up at the "my_city" location. We send a unit to "my_city" store and then When we click the button to notify the customer that the order is ready, it says that it is not ready. We have to go to the product page, edit the product, subtract 1 unit from the ecomm warehouse source, add 1 unit to the "my_city" store source, save (and in some cases reindex), then we can notify the customer.
This seems extremely tedious. I don't see any reports about stock that needs to transfer, or any simple and direct way to do this. Is this actually the default / intended functionality? Any help or clarification would be appreciated.
